# Junit doesn't call REST web service

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, junit, resteasy

I want to test a class which calls a RESTEasy webservice. It seems Junit doesn't call the webservice. I checked at server side, the request didnt reach.

```
public class EmpService {

  public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
      ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:8080/rest/employees");
      request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
      ClientResponse<Employees> response = null;

      try {
        response = request.get(Employees.class);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      Employees received = response.getEntity();
      if (received.getEmployees() == null){
        System.out.println("Employees is null");
      }
      return received.getEmployees();
    }
  }
```

My intention is not to test the REST service, it is to test the class `EmpService`. So I have written the following JUnit test case.

```
public class EmpServiceTest {

  @Test
  public void testGetEmployees() throws Exception {
    EmpService service = new EmpService();        
    List<Employees> employees = service.getEmployees();
    Assert.assertNotNull("Employees is null", employees);
  }

  @Test
  public void testREST() {
      ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:8080/rest/employees");
      request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
      ClientResponse<Employees> response = null;

      try {
        response = request.get(Employees.class);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      Employees received = response.getEntity();
      Assert.assertNotNull("Employees is null", received.getEmployees());
    }
}
```

I tested the REST service in browser and it is working fine. But Junit test case fails to call it and no error reported.
I tried to test the REST service directly in JUnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem is with the content-type. The JUnit side doesn't have a json mapper class. Used jackson json library and it worked fine.